# 200 amp panel with 3 wire service connected to outside disconnect

Tags: electrical-panel

If the main panel is fed with a 3 wire service and a generator transfer switch with a service disconnect was added - would it be considered a sub panel?

Comment: It's normal for a main panel to be fed with 3-wire (no ground) service.  You are asking, if you add a main-side generator transfer switch, does the transfer switch *become* the main panel?

Comment: Why, oh why, are you considering whole-house transfer here? It's generally far less risky in the long run (fewer fancy load-shed doodads which can break, and less chance of accidentally overloading the generator because you forgot a load-shed doodad somewhere, especially a risk when you start adding things down the road) to have the transfer switch feed a dedicated standby subpanel instead of trying to transfer the whole house.